# Receive from UDP, respond through TCP

Tags: tcp, udp, client-server

Im trying to write a server client program, where client sends request through UDP socket to a server, then server responds back to a client through TCP socket.
My question is, how can server establish a TCP connection back to a client after getting the request through UDP? 
I'll add code parts on Monday, but I more interested in pseudocode for that. Does that mean that the client should listen on tcp port after sending udp request? So confused

Comment: Yes, a server cannot just randomly connect to some client. The client has to open a listening socket, and the server needs to know the client's socket's address to connect to it. And the client has better have a waiting, listening socket before it sends this request, because there's absolutely nothing that guarantees that the client will be able to set up the socket after it sends its UDP datagram, but before the server turns around and tries to talk to it.

Comment: Can server get client's address and port from UDP request it received?

Comment: The UDP request itself indicates the IP address and the UDP port it came from.  You will have, at the very least, have the client inform the server what TCP port it's listening on, provided that it's the same IP address that the UDP datagram came from.